# TypeError: action is undefined on my searchbar redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This week i've been trying to create a searchbar filter, so i create a redux to work the change of state of the input values on the searchbar. When i tried to started with the redux properly connected, it gives me "action is undefined" assuming the error is inside my searchbar reducer. Could you guys help me kill that issue?

Here's my searchbar (input and button) and my MapStateToProps

```
                <div className={classes.searchbar} id="searchbar">
                <form id="Searchbar">
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="parametro" 
                    id="parametro" 
                    onChange={(e) => Filter(e.target.value)}
                    value={value}
                   />

                    <Searchbar link={"/produtos?nome=" + value}>    
                        <button type="submit" >
                            Pesquisar!
                        </button>
                    </Searchbar>
                </form>
            </div>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    isAuthenticated: state.authRdc.token,
    value: state.searchbarRdc.searchbar
};
```

};

here's my reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from 'store/actions/actionTypes';
import { updateObject } from 'utils/updater';

const initialState = {
    value: null,
    parametro: null
}

const Filter = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { value: action.searchbar });
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.UPDATE_FILTER:
            return Filter(state, action);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

and my action:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const Filter = (value) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.UPDATE_FILTER,
        value: value
    }
}
```

Comment: when you call `Filter(e.target.value)` did you map it with `mapDispatchToProps`? otherwise you should use `this.props.dispatch` see more info in the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/using-react-redux/connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapdispatchtoprops#connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapdispatchtoprops)

Comment: i made this on mapDispatchToProps  (im still a newbie when we talk about react-redux) and still gives me the same error :/

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        logout: () => dispatch(actionCreators.logout()),
        Filter: () => dispatch(actionCreators.Filter())
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are already done with this topic and you are a redux pro already. But still, it looks like you are forgetting a break-statement in your switch-case.

That could lead to the error. If you are still working with redux, you may already know the new [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/quick-start). It makes writing of every part of redux faster and it helps you to keep better overview. I would advise using typescript because of type safety but that's just a matter of choice.

Comment: break not required as it returns from the function